# Почему не работает мой код для решения задачи?

Tags: python

> Напишите программу, которая считывает строку с числом n, которое
> задаёт количество чисел, которые нужно считать. Далее считывает n
> строк с числами x_i, по одному числу в каждой строке. Итого будет
> n+1n+1 строк.
>
> При считывании числа x_i программа должна на отдельной строке вывести
> значение f(x_i).  Функция f(x) уже реализована и доступна для вызова.
>
> Функция вычисляется достаточно долго и зависит только от переданного
> аргумента x. Для того, чтобы уложиться в ограничение по времени, нужно
> избежать повторного вычисления значений.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 5
> 5
> 12
> 9
> 20
> 12
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 11
> 41
> 47
> 61
> 41
> ```

Такой код работает не правильно:

```
def f(x):
    return x**3
 
d = {}
a = []
 
for _ in range(int(input())):
    x = int(input())
    while True:
        try:
            a.append(d[x])
            break
        except KeyError:
            d[x] = f(x)
 
print(*a)
```

Comment: Возникает ошибка или не проходит проверку?

Comment: 1) вы затеняете `f`, по условию она уже определена, 2) выводить просят в каждое значение в отдельной строке 3) cached_f = functools.lru_cache(None)(f) заменит большую часть программы.